I just want to thank this community with all the respect I have for helping people to not get scammed
I just this morning got the bit coin mining scam and was excited to find out that I had $30,000+ in Bitcoin n to withdraw it after the 364 days of a 365 day period for $64. Well I decided to Google that n it led me here to find out it a scam. I can't thank this community enough for saving me my money n the embarrassment of calling my friends n telling them I just got $30,000 only to be embarrassed. Thank y'all again for this community n your infinite knowledge!

Everyone starts somewhere, consider yourself fortunate that you decided to do a little bit of research before proceeding. Bitcoiners always say "verify dont trust" and this applies to basically everything at this point.
